# While running Docker build the pip dependencies installation failed

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gunicorn, huggingface-transformers

I was trying to create a docker image for a sentiment analysis application. I have the dependencies as follows:

1. flask
2. transformers
3. optimum[onnxruntime]
4. gunicorn

I have the dockerfile as below:

```
 #Using the base image with python
 FROM python:3.8-alpine3.15
 
 #Set our working directory as app
 WORKDIR /app
 #Installing python dependencies
 RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 #COPY requirements.txt /
 RUN pip install flask transformers optimum[onnxruntime] gunicorn
 
 # Copy the models directory and app.py files
 COPY ["./models", "app.py", "./"]
 
 #Exposing the port 5000 from the container
 EXPOSE 5000
 #Starting the python application
 ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "--bind=127.0.0.1:5000", "app:app"]
```

But I get some errors while executing the following command:

```
sudo docker build -t sentiment-analysis:v001 .
```

The error as follows:

```
  Downloading optimum-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Downloading optimum-0.1.1.tar.gz (17 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
  Downloading optimum-0.1.0.tar.gz (16 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'optimum/version.py'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z7_0v3f_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z7_0v3f_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z7_0v3f_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 482, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z7_0v3f_/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
      AssertionError: Error: Could not open 'optimum/version.py' due [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'optimum/version.py'
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install flask transformers optimum[onnxruntime] gunicorn' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What could be the problem? Thank you in advance.

I have run my application using gunicorn with no error. Then I tried to create a docker image to deploy the application. But while creating the docker image I got the error mentioned in the post. I was expecting a docker image that could be deployed.

Comment: I think the Alpine-based images often have trouble installing prebuilt wheels; does it work better if your image is `FROM python:3.8` (not specifically Alpine)?

Comment: (It's not your immediate problem, but if your server binds to 127.0.0.1, it will bind to a container-private localhost interface and be unreachable from outside the container.  In the `CMD` you need to set `--bind=0.0.0.0:5000` instead.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for your suggestion. After using `FROM python:3.8` the dependencies got installed but that makes the image size very big (4.46GB). Do you have any idea how to reduce the size? I was using Alpine-based images at the first place because of the image size.